# Apache mod_rewrite discrepancy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Community,

I have the following problem: for a private project, I wanted to create nice urls with mod_rewrite.

Locally (Win 10, Apache 2.4.23) every rule in my .htaccess works fine.
Remotely (Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4.18) the first 3 rules don't work at all, specifically the all return a 404 not found error.

Please take a look:

```
# Basic site rules
RewriteRule ^login$ /login.php
RewriteRule ^logout$ /login.php?logout
RewriteRule ^signup$ /signup.php
RewriteRule ^confirm/(.*)$ /signup.php?confirm&regkey=$1

# mail list
RewriteRule ^mails$ /manage_mail.php
RewriteRule ^mail/list/ip$ /manage_mail.php?mode=create_iplist
RewriteRule ^mail/list/usernames$ /manage_mail.php?mode=create_usernamelist

and more rules here...
```

Rules 1-3 (login, logout, signup) return the aforementioned 404 error.
Every following rule works as intended.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Edit #1: scratched

Edit #2: This is the VHost i'm using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.me
    ServerAdmin postmaster@domain.me
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.me/html
    <Directory /var/www/domain.me/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog  "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/www/domain.me/log/%Y-%m/error_%Y-%m-%d.log"
    CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/www/domain.me/log/%Y-%m/access_%Y-%m-%d.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/apache2/apache2.conf looks quite similar.

Comment: Are you sure that in the Apache's config files for localhost, the `AllowOverride All` option is set on that directory?

Comment: can you access the pages under their long name ( `/login.php` etc)?

Comment: Are you sure that its not the browser caching the 404 from previous requests to those urls.

Best way to check this is using the `curl` cli utility:
`curl -I http://www.example.com/login`

Comment: Did you also try it without that `FollowSymLinks` option?

Comment: No, I didn't. See my own answer. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @artur99 yes it's set

Comment: @neuhaus yes, I can

Comment: @Euperia  no, I cleared the cache, tried force refresh.... Even with Postman it didn't work so I supposed it wouldn't work with plain cURL either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for you help, I found the solution myself. The problem was the MultiViews Option in

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.me/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Once I removed it and reloaded the config, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that occurs sometimes when the `AllowOverride` option is not set `All` in the apache's configurations.

I don't know where you've set your configurations, but I'll suppose you have them in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

In that file, you must go to the `<Directory "LOCATION">` tag where's set the location of your `public_html`[1] folder, and add the `AllowOverride All` parameter.

Or, if you can't find that directory, just add at the end a new `<Directory>` tag for the `public_html` folder.

It should look like this:

```
<Directory "folder_location">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

[1] I'm assuming that's the name of the folder where you have your php files.

Comment: I expanded my question.